# curl cannot connect to HTTPS sites in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ssl, curl

I recently upgrade to 18.04 from 17.10, and now `curl` and various other programs no longer connect to HTTPS sites.

Here's an example `curl` invocation:

```
$ curl -v https://httpbin.org/get
*   Trying 52.3.63.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to httpbin.org (52.3.63.2) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:141B306E:SSL routines:tls_collect_extensions:bad extension
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:141B306E:SSL routines:tls_collect_extensions:bad extension
```

Using `openssl` directly has no problems, so I don't think it's there, and I haven't found anything online. Is this a known bug in 18.04?

Comment: I tested this on a 18.04 system now. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had installed my own version of `openssl` a long time ago (2 years) that was being considered as newer than the one provided by the default repositories. Simply reinstalling the correct version fixed my issue.